# Error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getKeyName() on a non-object", but without table?

Tags: component, php

I write a small component to export data from a shop component, this is my first component, i get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getKeyName() on a non-object PATH\legacy\model\admin.php on line 885", i found some solution, but my problem is i don't wont new table, and my question is how can i avoid new sql table? Because i work with tables of already existing components and they are not edited with my component.

My sources:

```
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=620&t=666986
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156707/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getkeyname
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313272/error-call-to-a-member-function-getkeyname-component-for-joomla-2-5
```

I understand from this solution that i need a new table, but i don't need it...

Comment: Please can you show us some code?

Comment: Here is my model file: http://pastebin.com/6HG7qvDS, and my form file is: http://pastebin.com/U51WT5Xs

Comment: Your pastes disappeared. Also are you perhaps using something other then `JModelLegacy`? If its list or item I think it "assumes" there is a table attached.

Comment: @JordanRamstad no, i use JModelAdmin, i published files again: http://pastebin.com/Ev3P9f3v & http://pastebin.com/w18EbFPj

Comment: What function is running for line 885 of `legacy/model/admin.php`? I'm guessing that is the save method, which then raises the question, how are you saving date if not to a table?!

Comment: I was wrong in my last comment it is actually `JModelAdmin` Only that assumes there is a table attached, though its also the only one integrated with `JForm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JForm` usually maps to the columns of a database table when used with `JModelAdmin`, so if the name of a column is `add` it looks for add to be a column in that table.

If you look into the content component (articles) and inspect some of the form fields, then look at the database table for content you will see their names match. If you want to use `JForm` the best way is to apply your own logic to it, so use `JModelLegacy` with a controller to catch and direct save to your own model function, rather then the default.

For pretty much every function in `JModelAdmin` it adds `$table = $this->getTable();` to be able to pass or retrieve the data from the table. However with `JModelLegacy` there is no direct connection to `JForm` but by the sounds of it you just want the clean way to display the forms, so it is probably best to just add that logic to your view class anyway (the `view.html.php`)

However you could override the save/retrieve functions of `JModelAdmin` to make use of it, but all in all it might be more work then just using `JModelLegacy` in my opinion. It forces less on you and gives you the ability to customize your code more if you are not using the typical Joomla way of using tables.

Answer (score 0):

I copyed the model-file from another component. Than i renamed the important places in the file. In my case, i forgot to change the the prefix value in the function getTable. Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for taking your first syep as a contributor. However, I don't find your answer to be tailored to the OP's question.  It seems that you are expressing how you solved your own issue which may have overlapping details with this question.  When you answer a question please be very careful to precisely answer the question which is described in the question.

Comment: Please take our [tour] and read [answer]. If you don't mind, please introduce yourself and tell us about your Joomla experience by editing your profile.